# void arithmetic in C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I have a structure:

```
struct {
  Header header;
  uint32_t var1;
  uint32_t var2;
  char var3;
  char var4[4];
};
```

You get the hint. The thing is that I am receiving byte arrays over the network, and I first have to parse the Header first. So I first parse the header first, and then I have to parse the rest of the structure.

I tried,

```
void* V = data;  // which is sizeof(uint32_t) * 2 + sizeof(char) * 5
```

and then try to parse it like (V), V+sizeof(uint32_t) ... etc. etc.

but it gave compiler errors. How do I parse the rest of this struct over the network?

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on `void*`. Although some compilers allow it as an extension, you should cast it to `char*` instead.

Comment: what is name of structure?
You should not do arithmetic like `sizeof(uint32_t) * 2 + sizeof(char) * 5` as there may be padding of bytes in-between structure members.

Comment: What does the number of bytes a `uint32_t` takes up on your platform have to do with a network wire format that's platform-independent? Your use of `sizeof` is manifestly incorrect. You should be using the sizes from the specification for the network protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental unit of data in C++ is `char`. It is the smallest type that can be addressed, and it has size one by definition. Moreover, the language rules specifically allow all data to be viewed as a sequence of chars. All I/O happens in terms of sequences (or streams) of chars.

Therefore, your raw data buffer should be a `char` array.

(On the other hand, a `void *` has very specific and limited use in C++; it's main purpose is to designate an object's *address* in memory. For example, the result of `operator new()` is a `void *`.)